# Add white spaces to an image to fit to a specific resolution

Tags: android, image, image-processing, bitmap, android-bitmap

In apps like [NoCrop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rcplatform.nocrop&hl=en) an image is made to fit a resolution of 1:1 (made square) by adding some extra spaces at the top and bottom of the image (shown below).

[image: This is a square image, just for and example, although I don't need to make them square, I need to make them rectangular in 16:9 ratio]

Similarly, I wish to add some spaces to an image through my Android app, to fit a resolution of ratio, say 16:9. My app creates a video by stitching these images together, and for the video, all the images first need to be converted into a fixed resolution.
I have not used Bitmaps much, nor I am an expert in Android. Any kind of help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to your `ImageView` in xml:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

This will crop your image so that it fits the `ImageView`